# How to get the workbook ref in Apache POI formula (e.g. formula [CELL])?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to implement a Excel formula that is [CELL function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cell.php) use the Apache POI.

It will return the Current Excel workbook filename when the cell eval expression is `=CELL("filename")`.

I could find the cell's sheet from AreaEval type in other eval expression. Except the `CELL` expression that only one argument.

```
public class CELL implements  Function1Arg, Function2Arg {
    @Override
    public ValueEval evaluate(int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex, ValueEval arg0) {

        return evaluate(srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex, arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public ValueEval evaluate(int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex, ValueEval arg0, ValueEval arg1) {
        return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public ValueEval evaluate(ValueEval[] args, int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex) {
        switch (args.length) {
            case 1:
                return evaluate(srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex, args[0]);
            case 2:
                return evaluate(srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex, args[0], args[1]);
        }
        return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID;
    }
}
```

Is there somewhere may let me get the Eval expression's workbook reference?

Comment: How would this work though? Apache POI is very happy to open a file from any old InputStream, so in many cases there won't be a filename!

Comment: @Gagravarr Er,yes,there are many way to get the filename and the workbook properties. But I think the formula eval class should not access external env directly as the Apache POI formula. So, It's can't just get the those properties from a global variable of my App. There is some way to got the ref of the currently workbook that formula cell belong I think. Otherwise I could do this use the dirty solution.

Comment: Not sure I follow you? If the workbook was opened by reading an InputStream from a remote network server, or a database, or many other sources, then there isn't a "filename" to go with that InputStream!

Comment: @Gagravarr My point is that is very dirty in the formula eval class of Apache POI access the application static variable directly. That make the formula eval class limit to this situation and could not be a popular formula eval class in the Apache POI.